# Unexpected error when compiling

Tags: c, unix, struct

I'm doing a C program in Unix that simulate a F1 race.
There is a problem in one of my struct and I can't identify the problem.

My first struct :

```
typedef struct { 
int NumVoiture; /* numéro de la voiture : 1..24 Ne pas oublier d'ajouter 1 si number >= 13 lors de l'affichage */ 
int Status; /* le statut de la voiture, ARRETCOURT, Abandon, etc... */ 
int TourActuel; /* le numéro du tour actuel de la voiture */ 
int SecteurActuel; /* le numéro du secteur actuel de la voiture (0..2) */ 
TempsDuTour TempsDuTour; /* le temps du tour courant */ 
TempsDuTour MeilleurTour; /* le meilleur de temps de la séance pour cette voiture */ 
TempsDuTour MeilleursSecteurs; /* chaque meilleur secteur de la séance pour cette voiture */ 
struct timeval HeureFinSecteur[NBSECTEURS]; /* heure de passage à la fin de chaque secteur */ 
struct timeval HeureDebutSecteur; /* heure (précision à la microsec) au début d'un secteur, voir timeval sur le net */ 
} Voiture;
```

And my second struct :

```
typedef struct 
{ 
int NumVoiture; 
int TypeDeSeance; 
DonneesPartagees * Voiture; 
DonneesPartagees * Session; 
DonneesPartagees * CompressionTemporelle; /* compression temporelle */ 
Voiture ** Rang; /* tableau de pointeurs */ 
} Containeur;
```

The problem appears when I tried to use that function :

```
void initContaineur(Containeur * x, int NumVoiture, int TypeDeSeance, DonneesPartagees * Voiture, DonneesPartagees * Session, DonneesPartagees * CompressionTemporelle, Voiture ** Rang) 
{ 
x->NumVoiture = NumVoiture; 
x->TypeDeSeance = TypeDeSeance; 
x->Voiture = Voiture; 
x->Session = Session; 
x->CompressionTemporelle = CompressionTemporelle; 
x->Rang = Rang; 
}
```

The error says

```
expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'Voiture'
```

There is a second error when I call "Voiture * Rang[NBVOITURES];" in the main()

```
'Rang' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You have `Voiture` as both a type and a struct field.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: That's allowed: struct fields reside in a separate namespace from other identifiers. The problem, as jwodder says in his/her answer, is that this code is trying to use it as a variable-name as well, which conflicts with the type-identifier use.

Comment: @ruakh: I wasn't sure about the validity, but it is nevertheless an extremely dubious practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first typedef makes `Voiture` the name of a type, yet in `initContainer` you're trying to use `Voiture` as the name of a parameter.  Obviously, this causes problems, and you need to rename one of them.

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't say "obviously". There are many languages where type-identifiers and variable-names reside in separate namespaces. (And even in C, it would be safe to have a `struct Voiture` alongside a variable named `Voiture`.)